# How to show a SfBusyIndicator on a button click? c# xamarin.android azure android

Tags: c#, android, azure, xamarin, xamarin.android

Actually i want to create a loading dailog on a button click.

i have followed this tutorial http://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin-android/sfbusyindicator/getting-started

this is my Button.

```
Button btnCLick = Findviewbyid<button>(resource.id.btnclikc);
btnCLick.Click += btnCLick_CLICK;
void btnCLick_Click (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
// here i need to start a dailog box like loading.
// but i use a Sync fusion busy indicator here.
// 
sfBusyIndicator = new SfBusyIndicator(this);
        sfBusyIndicator.TextColor = Color.Rgb(62,101,254);
        sfBusyIndicator.AnimationType = AnimationTypes.DoubleCircle;
        sfBusyIndicator.ViewBoxWidth = 200;
        sfBusyIndicator.ViewBoxHeight = 200;
        sfBusyIndicator.TextSize = 60;
        sfBusyIndicator.Title = "Loading ... Please Wait ...";

 sfBusyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
// a Lot of work is done here for around 15 seconds. a database connection is called.
 sfBusyIndicator.IsBusy = false;

// again some work

 StartActivity(typeof(ACT));
}
```

The Busyindicator dosent come up.

and after the connection is completed and all the work of 15 seconds is done the activity gets started. and when the activity starts the loading just popup. this means after the whole work is completed the loading screen gets started.

how can i make the loading screen start when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

[`SfBusyIndicator` is a View](http://help.syncfusion.com/cr/xamarin-android/sfbusyindicator), it needs to be a part of your currently shown Layout. Something in the likes of:

```
<LinearLayout
    ... />
    <Com.Syncfusion.Sfbusyindicator.SfBusyIndicator
       android:id="@+id/indicator"
       ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then find it in your activity:

```
var indicator = FindViewById<SfBusyIndicator>(Resource.Id.indicator);
indicator.TextColor = Color.Rgb(62,101,254);
indicator.AnimationType = AnimationTypes.DoubleCircle;
indicator.ViewBoxWidth = 200;
indicator.ViewBoxHeight = 200;
indicator.TextSize = 60;
indicator.Title = "Loading ... Please Wait ...";
```

Comment: it Gives a error Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class Com.Syncfusion.sfBusyIndicator.SfBusyIndicator

Comment: The indicator can be initialised in either code or xml.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the busy indicator to a containing layout/view before it will be displayed. eg.

```
sfBusyIndicator = new SfBusyIndicator(this);
    sfBusyIndicator.TextColor = Color.Rgb(62,101,254);
    sfBusyIndicator.AnimationType = AnimationTypes.DoubleCircle;
    sfBusyIndicator.ViewBoxWidth = 200;
    sfBusyIndicator.ViewBoxHeight = 200;
    sfBusyIndicator.TextSize = 60;
    sfBusyIndicator.Title = "Loading ... Please Wait ...";

sfBusyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
FrameLayout busyIndicatorHolder = new FrameLayout(this);
busyIndicatorHolder.AddView(sfBusyIndicator);

// a Lot of work is done here for around 15 seconds. a database connection is 
called.

sfBusyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
```

If your "Lot of work is done ..." is an AsyncTask then I would put the call to sfBusyIndicator.IsBusy=true in the PreExecute of the task and the IsBusy = false; in the PostExecute.

Hope it helps